# Adding jquery to php mysql based pagination

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am working on a PHP-Mysql based website which has some large lists to display(for example product lists).Now I had to break it down to pages for the convenience of the user.So I have added pagination using PHP.Now this does a page refresh each time I click on the page number.So I have a base with PHP/MySQL and want to add **Ajax/jquery** to it for avoiding **unnecessary page refresh**.How can I add pagination to the existing code that I have??
Here is the php code for reference.

```
        <div class="flt width710">
            <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="flt mapnewalert"> <?php //echo ucfirst($_SESSION['$city']) ?></div>
            <div style="float:right" id="toppagesel">
            <?php 
                    echo $pages->display_pages();
                    echo $pages->display_items_per_page();
                    //echo "<span class=\"\">".$pages->display_jump_menu()."</span>";
                    $query = "SELECT * from properties,locality,cities where properties.city_id='".$_SESSION['$cityId']."' and properties.locality_id=locality.locality_id and properties.city_id=cities.city_id $pages->limit";
                    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

                    //$getProperty =    $propertyDetails->getPropertyDetailsByCityIdPaginate($_SESSION['$cityId'],$limit);
            ?>
            <?php //echo $pages->display_pages(); ?><?php //echo $pages->display_items_per_page();?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And the pagination class:

```
         class Paginator{
var $items_per_page;
var $items_total;
var $current_page;
var $num_pages;
var $mid_range;
var $low;
var $limit;
var $return;
var $default_ipp;
var $querystring;
var $ipp_array;

          function Paginator()
{
    $this->current_page = 1;
    $this->mid_range = 2;
    $this->ipp_array = array(2,4,6,8,'All');
    $this->items_per_page = (!empty($_GET['ipp'])) ? $_GET['ipp']:$this->default_ipp;
}

          function paginate()
{
    if(!isset($this->default_ipp)) $this->default_ipp=2;
    if($_GET['ipp'] == 'All')
    {
        $this->num_pages = 1;
          //    $this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;
    }
    else
    {
        if(!is_numeric($this->items_per_page) OR $this->items_per_page <= 0) $this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;
        $this->num_pages = ceil($this->items_total/$this->items_per_page);
    }
    $this->current_page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1 ; // must be numeric > 0
    $prev_page = $this->current_page-1;
    $next_page = $this->current_page+1;
    if($_GET)
    {
        $args = explode("&",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
        foreach($args as $arg)
        {
            $keyval = explode("=",$arg);
            if($keyval[0] != "page" And $keyval[0] != "ipp") $this->querystring .= "&" . $arg;
        }
    }

    if($_POST)
    {
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$val)
        {
            if($key != "page" And $key != "ipp") $this->querystring .= "&$key=$val";
        }
    }
    if($this->num_pages > 4)
    {
        $this->return = ($this->current_page > 1 And $this->items_total >= 10) ? "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$prev_page&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring\">&laquo; Previous</a> ":"<span class=\"inactive\" href=\"#\">&laquo; Previous</span> ";

        $this->start_range = $this->current_page - floor($this->mid_range/2);
        $this->end_range = $this->current_page + floor($this->mid_range/2);

        if($this->start_range <= 0)
        {
            $this->end_range += abs($this->start_range)+1;
            $this->start_range = 1;
        }
        if($this->end_range > $this->num_pages)
        {
            $this->start_range -= $this->end_range-$this->num_pages;
            $this->end_range = $this->num_pages;
        }
        $this->range = range($this->start_range,$this->end_range);

        for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)
        {
            if($this->range[0] > 2 And $i == $this->range[0]) $this->return .= " ... ";
            // loop through all pages. if first, last, or in range, display
            if($i==1 Or $i==$this->num_pages Or in_array($i,$this->range))
            {
                $this->return .= ($i == $this->current_page And $_GET['page'] != 'All') ? "<a title=\"Go to page $i of $this->num_pages\" class=\"current\" href=\"#\">$i</a> ":"<a class=\"paginate\" title=\"Go to page $i of $this->num_pages\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$i&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring\">$i</a> ";
            }
            if($this->range[$this->mid_range-1] < $this->num_pages-1 And $i == $this->range[$this->mid_range-1]) $this->return .= " ... ";
        }
        $this->return .= (($this->current_page < $this->num_pages And $this->items_total >= 10) And ($_GET['page'] != 'All') And $this->current_page > 0) ? "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$next_page&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring\">Next &raquo;</a>\n":"<span class=\"inactive\" href=\"#\">&raquo; Next</span>\n";
        $this->return .= ($_GET['page'] == 'All') ? "<a class=\"current\" style=\"margin-left:10px\" href=\"#\">All</a> \n":"<a class=\"paginate\" style=\"margin-left:10px\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=1&ipp=All$this->querystring\">All</a> \n";
    }
    else
    {
        for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)
        {
            $this->return .= ($i == $this->current_page) ? "<a class=\"current\" href=\"#\">$i</a> ":"<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$i&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring\">$i</a> ";
        }
        $this->return .= "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=1&ipp=All$this->querystring\">All</a> \n";
    }
    $this->low = ($this->current_page <= 0) ? 0:($this->current_page-1) * $this->items_per_page;
    if($this->current_page <= 0) $this->items_per_page = 0;
    $this->limit = ($_GET['ipp'] == 'All') ? "":" LIMIT $this->low,$this->items_per_page";
}

   }
```

How can I achieve it??I referred other threads and tried but couldn't get it working in my context.I am a newbie to ajax jquery part so sorry if its a easy task!! :P

PS: Is this possible in the current scenario or do I have to make the changes to my pagination class and php code.Please throw some light on it!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
$('.paginate').live('click', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var btnPage = $(this);
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : btnPage.attr('href'),
        success : function(resp)
        {
            // replace current results with new results.
            $('#project_section').html(resp);
        },
        error : function()
        {
            window.location.href = btnPage.attr('href');
        }
    });
});
```

});

Here `$(".paginate")` is the class of the `<li>` in my paginator class.
I got the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928368/paginate-records-on-client-side-issue)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are many JavaScript pagination library will help you to simplify your work,

can you try this pagination library,

Demo: http://www.frequency-decoder.com/demo/table-sort-revisited/paginate/

Website: http://www.frequency-decoder.com/2007/10/19/client-side-table-pagination-script/

Comment: thank you very much for the prompt reply,but I would like something that suits the above code or I would have to revisit the logic.Can't I just replace the div with the new one using ajax ?? Something similar suggested here, but I was not able to get it working- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755118/how-to-add-ajax-on-existing-php-mysql-based-pagination